# Create Facebook Application from Existing Facebook Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebooker

Does anyone know if it is possible to create a

```
Facebook Application
```

using an

```
Existing Facebook Application?
```

If that's not possible does anyone know if it is possible to restrict what permission we will use for each request that we make?

Found:

[Creating Application with FBJS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs/createApplication/)

But what does Child Application mean? Is it a new application or the new application will have all permissions of the old one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Facebook.createApplication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs/createApplication/) is currently the only way for a Facebook app to create another app.  Permissions for the parent app are not inherited by its children.  Note: this call is deprecated, please keep an eye on the [Developer Blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/) for future plans.